# dplyr group_by and any command giving unexpected output

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a sample data set:

```
> temp
     ID Visit Issue SpecialExclusion
1  X123     5 12345            FALSE
2  X123     5 67890            FALSE
3  X123     5 34934            FALSE
31 X123     6 34934            FALSE
4  X123     6 67890            FALSE


primaryIssue <- c("12345")
excludedIssue <- c("12345", "67890")
```

What I want is to exclude the exluded issue only if the primary issue is there as well.

```
> temp %>% group_by(Visit)  %>%  mutate(SpecialExclusion = ifelse(any(Issue ==primaryIssue), Issue %in% excludedIssues, SpecialExclusion))
Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: Visit

    ID Visit Issue SpecialExclusion
1 X123     5 12345             TRUE
2 X123     5 67890             TRUE
3 X123     5 34934             TRUE
4 X123     6 34934            FALSE
5 X123     6 67890            FALSE
```

However, this does seem to work:

```
> temp %>% group_by(Visit) %>% mutate(SpecialExclusion = if(any(Issue == primaryIssue)){Issue %in% excludedIssue}else{SpecialExclusion})
Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
Groups: Visit

    ID Visit Issue SpecialExclusion
1 X123     5 12345             TRUE
2 X123     5 67890             TRUE
3 X123     5 34934            FALSE
4 X123     6 34934            FALSE
5 X123     6 67890            FALSE
```

So why does the `ifelse` fail but the 'if-then` work? Thanks!

Comment: `any` isn't doing what you think it is

Comment: I want to check if any of the Issues in the Visit are part of ExcludedIssues. If at least one of them is, I want to change all the Issues within ExcludedIssues to be True. So I check : "Are `any(temp$issues)`, excluded? -- if yes--  return me a TRUE if the issue is in `excludedIssues`. Why is the logic wrong?

Comment: What answer were you expecting for the `SpecialExclusion` column

Comment: I was expecting TRUE, FALSE

Comment: I've attached a more robust example

Comment: be sure to add the desired output in the example also

Comment: You probably just need an "and statement" with the two conditions. See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
temp %>%
  group_by(Visit) %>%
  mutate(SpecialExclusion = any(Issue %in% primaryIssue) & Issue %in% excludedIssue)
# Source: local data frame [5 x 4]
# Groups: Visit
# 
#     ID Visit Issue SpecialExclusion
# 1 X123     5 12345             TRUE
# 2 X123     5 67890             TRUE
# 3 X123     5 34934            FALSE
# 4 X123     6 34934            FALSE
# 5 X123     6 67890            FALSE
```

You asked about what is going on with `ifelse`. Look at this example:

```
ifelse(1 == 1, 2:3, 4:5)
[1] 2
if(1 == 1) 2:3 else 4:5
[1] 2 3
```

In this simple example, I test if 1 is equal to 1. If it is TRUE, return the numbers 2 and 3. `ifelse` doesn't seem to want to return more than one value. It just takes the first value, 2, and gives that as output. That is what your function is doing. So then wouldn't everyone use `if` at all times since it is more flexible? Look at this example:

```
ifelse(1:5 == 1, 'a', 'b')
[1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "b"
```

We tested if the sequence 1 through 5 is equal to 1. The first instance should be TRUE and the rest should be FALSE. `ifelse` performs the way we expect. But `if` is expecting one value only for the test.

```
if(1:5 == 1) 'a' else 'b'
[1] "a"
Warning message:
In if (1:5 == 1) "a" else "b" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

It gives us a warning and one `'a'` because that was the first result of the test. The `if` statement wanted one conditional test, we gave it five different TRUE's and FALSE's.

So `ifelse` is good for many tests that produce one output. And `if` is good for one test that produces many outputs.

Comment: This gives the same result as my `if-else`. However, why doesn't the `ifelse` work? Also this won't quite work. If I had another function modify the the "SpecialExclusion" column, your method will overwrite whatever was there before. My method would not.

Comment: That's because `ifelse` is returning the first value of the condition.

Comment: Sorry-- can you expand that a bit more-- what do you mean "first value of the condition"?